# round a float and multiply character by it(c)* update

Tags: c, concatenation

Can anyone help with the following code?
New to c from python so I know my code is wrong.
I trying to make a code that can round down a float and multiply a char by said float

```
float avg;
char star='*';
float top;
float bottom;

top=50;
bottom=80;


avg=(top/bottom*10);
star*=avg;
printf("%c\n",star);
printf("%d\n",top);
printf("%d\n",bottom);
printf("%f\n",avg);
```

output needs to be

```
* * * * * *   
50  
80     
6.25
```

what I'm getting is

```
♠ 
50
80
6.25
```

I've also tried to use floor to round the avg but that just turns the spade into a different character and 6.25 becomes 6.00000000000000

Comment: Did you expect `star *= avg;` to produce `"* * * * * *"`? That's not how it works, C is not Python.

Comment: I've only ever used python before so I have no idea how to do this in c.

Comment: Either you make `floor(avg)` calls to `printf` that each print one `'*'`, or you create a `char stars[(int)avg + 1];` and fill that with `'*'`, and a 0 to terminate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a loop to display your `*`s;

```
for( int i = 0; i < avg; ++ i ) {
    printf( "* " );
}
printf( "\n" );
```

(get rid of the `star` variable).

To explain the behaviour you saw: when you do `star *= avg;`, what actually happens is the ascii value of star, which is `*` => 42, gets multiplied by avg, which is 6.25. This produces 262.5, which is shortened (modulo 256) to 6.5 and the decimal is removed (6), to fit in a char again. 6 in ascii isn't usually a visible character (technically it's "acknowledge"), but in the codepage you're using, it turns out it's drawn as a spade symbol.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<avg ; ++i)
   printf("%c",star);
printf("\n");
```

In C, when you multiply an `char` and an float you got another float (your first float multiplied by the ascii code of the `char`), because you are printing like an char `printf` will cast the float to char and print the corresponding char.